# Write HTML code in a QString

Tags: html, qt, qstring

I'm working with the QT Creator and I would like to write a HTML code into a QString or to set a textEdit with setHtml(). The problem is, that I cannot really escape the special characters that come with the HTML code, e.g. :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-    html40/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head><body style=" font-family:'.Lucida Grande UI'; font-size:13pt;     font-weight:400; font-style:normal;">
```

How can I write something like this to a QString or directly set it to the textEdit?

I need this because my HTML text may change.

Answer (score 3):

There's an easy way for that!
If you are using Qt5, just use

```
QString::toHtmlEscaped()
```

Example (from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html)):

```
QString plain = "#include <QtCore>";
QString html = plain.toHtmlEscaped();
// html == "#include &lt;QtCore&gt;"
```

If you are using Qt4:

```
Qt::escape
```

Example:

```
QString plain = "#include <QtCore>";
Qstring html = Qt::escape(plain);
```

Comment: Thank you, I already found that function. But the problem is: when I'm defining a QString with the HTML-code mentioned above, the QT underlines the string and says that it has found errors. Further, I think that the example is incorrect, isn't there a ";" missing at the end of the firs line (the error is also in the QT documentation).

Comment: This is strange...can you post a short snippet of code? Maybe, even others could help. Regarding the missing semicolon, I've spotted it, and I already edited the answer. Hope that we can find the issue.

Comment: Of course. It looks like this:

    QString test = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
     <html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style     type="text/css">
    p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }";

The whole line is then underlined red and I cannot write further code after this line. If I do like in the example it shows me an error when building the program.

Comment: Can you show the exact error? By the way, I'm almost sure that the anomaly relies in those double quotes inside the string: the compiler interprets the QString this way: QString test = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC " and the other charactes are left away, causing the error. Have you tried to explicity escaping the double quotes? I hope this won't interfere with toHtmlEscaped().

Comment: Is there any way to post a screenshot here? I figured something out:
When I take the HTML-Code line by line, meaning that I put each line into a QString and escape the double quotes it works fine. But my HTML-Code is pretty long and I don't want to put every line into a variable. Is there maybe any other way to modify the text of a textEdit "by hand"? I mean to add bold text etc..

Comment: @Darius Yes, [Screenshots can be embedded into posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/238205) (not comments).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking simply how to escape a C string. You'll need to use an online tool, such as http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/addslashes-stripslashes.html, or a command line tool like `echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC...' | sed -e 's-"-\"-g' > escaped.c`, or any text editor's replace functionality - say NotePad++'s.

Using such a tool, your string becomes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-    html40/strict.dtd\">rn<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">rnp, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }rn</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'.Lucida Grande UI\'; font-size:13pt;     font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">
```

Just add a double quote at the beginning and at the end and you're all set:

```
auto foo = QStringLiteral("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-    html40/strict.dtd\">rn<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">rnp, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }rn</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'.Lucida Grande UI\'; font-size:13pt;     font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">");
```